# Website looks different in safari/chrome on tablet

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, slider, tablet

I've tried to figure out what the problem. I've tried various browsers at different resolutions on my pc, and everything seems to be fine. However on my tablet, the evo slider on the right side sticks out from the container about 5-10px. 
[example 2 - tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR48A.jpg)
[example 1 - pc](http://www.bestinslot.org)

Comment: need to add some code - jsfiddle>

Comment: It is not a browser issue. It just depends on the window witdh. Just reduce the browser width on your computer and you will probably get that same issue.
Even though, I do not understand what your question is.

Comment: How do you solve it? Evo slider seems to override any changes I make involving setting a max-width / min-width. I have to set my width with javascript, however that doesn't seem to work either. I can't really post the evoslider jscript seeing as it's a paid product, and I doubt they'd like me throwing their code up there.

Comment: You tried to set the max-width/min-width of which element?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that would work but you could try changing the width of the `#content` element to a fixed width.
Right now the css seems to contain this:

```
#content{
  min-width: 960px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Try to change or override it to:

```
#content{
  width: 1000px;
}
```